# Problem uploading code to Arduino Uno using stino

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, ubuntu

I am having problems uploading my code to my Arduino Uno. The code that's already up, is running normally. The error code I get is:

```
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Connection timed out
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
ioctl("TIOCMSET"): Connection timed out
[Stino - Error 1]
```